# Creating tables based on multiple categorical variables

Tags: r

Good day everyone

I have a dataframe of the form

```
market<- c('Market_3','Market_1','Market_1','Market_2','Market_2')
accomod_type<-c('Hotel','Other','Private_Home','Condo','Sharing_economy')
age<-c(40,20,30,40,55)
length_stay<-c(7,6,5,7,9)
arrivals<-c(100,50,25,30,45)

my_df <- data.frame(market,accomod_type,age,length_stay,arrivals)
```

I want to make a table similar to the picture attached [image: picture] where I can show an average or totals for the 3 continuous variables in the df, based on the two categorical variables.

I've been trying xtabs of ftable but these don't generate what I need.

Any guidance on how to achieve the table attached?

Comment: @Pax thanks this is a start for sure but if I try to pipe as a data frame and then try to then pipe into gt() as an example I get this error message `Error in `dplyr::as_tibble()`:
! Column names `Market_1`, `Market_2`, `Market_3`, `Market_1`, `Market_2`, and 1 more must not be duplicated.` Getting unique column names proves a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Perhaps the code helps you to get started.

A combination of `aggregate()` and `xtabs()` is useful to produce the averages based on the two categorical variables. Watch out the orders matter. With `do.call(cbind, ...)` we produce a single dataframe.

```
y <- do.call(
  what = cbind,          
  args = lapply(X = c("length_stay", "arrivals", "age"),
                FUN = \(x) 
                xtabs(formula = get(x) ~ Group.1 + Group.2,
                      data = aggregate(x = cbind(length_stay, arrivals, age),
                                       by = list(accomod_type, market),                       
                                       FUN = mean, data = my_df))))
```

I think it's a matter of taste how you style the output then.

```
# install.packages("htmlTable")
library(htmlTable)
y |> htmlTable(x = _,
               rgroup = "Accomodation Type ",
               n.rgroup = 5L,
               cgroup = paste("Market", 1L:3L),
               header = rep(x = c("Avg lof", "Avg a", "Avg age"), times = 3L),
               n.cgroup = rep(x = 3L, times = 3L))
```

Edit: If you need `{library(gt)}`:

```
# install.packages("gt")
library(gt)

rn_y <- rownames(y)
cn_y <- c("Avg. Length of Stay", "Avg. Arrivals", "Avg. Age")

y |>
  unname() |>
  as.data.frame(row.names = rn_y) |>
  gt(rownames_to_stub = TRUE) |>
  # start from here 
  
  tab_stubhead(label = "Accomodation Type") |>
  tab_spanner(label = "Market 1",
              columns = paste0("V", 1L:3L)) |>
  tab_spanner(label = "Market 2",
              columns = paste0("V", 4L:6L)) |>
  tab_spanner(label = "Market 3",
              columns = paste0("V", 7L:9L)) |>
  # see ?cols_label for styling tipps
  cols_label(
    V1 = cn_y[[1L]], 
    V2 = cn_y[[2L]], 
    V3 = cn_y[[3L]], 
    
    V4 = cn_y[[1L]], 
    V5 = cn_y[[2L]], 
    V6 = cn_y[[3L]], 
    
    V7 = cn_y[[1L]], 
    V8 = cn_y[[2L]], 
    V9 = cn_y[[3L]] 
    ) |>
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = "lightgrey"),
            locations = cells_body(rows = seq(1L, 5L, 2L)))
```

This really is an ugly approach. There exist more elegant ways. Please read the help pages and documentation of `{gt}`.

Comment: this is brilliant.  Thanks. Just for reference though if I wanted to do just the frequencies and not the average how would I change the `FUN=mean` argument?

Comment: `lapply(X = my_df[, c("length_stay", "arrivals", "age")], 
       \(i)  xtabs(formula = i ~ my_df$accomod_type + my_df$market))`?